# C: strange behavior of wrong initialization of array

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int step;
    double position[4];
    position[0] = 1;
    for (step = 1;step<=4;step++){
        position[step] = 99;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

can compile without error and the resulting program can run.

However,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int step;
    double position[3];
    position[0] = 1;
    for (step = 1;step<=3;step++){
        position[step] = 99;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

can compile also but the program cannot run: The error is `Abort trap: 6`.

In both cases above, the (wrongly) initialized array is of size one less than what I fill in the for loop. But why do `4` and `3` make a difference here?

Now, more interestingly,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int step;
    double position[4];
    position[0] = 1;
    position[1] = 99;
    position[2] = 99;
    position[3] = 99;
    position[4] = 99;
    return 0;
}
```

cannot even compile (Error is `array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements`). So why does for loop make a difference here?

Comment: there is no array bound check in `c`. It will Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: It is **undefined behavior**. Standard doesn't guarantee *anything*; There may or may not be compile error or runtime error. It might even wipe your all data, because there is no guarantee.

Comment: In first two cases assignment of value to the array will be done in runtime. But in third case it will be in compile time. So it throws error.

Comment: @ikh Don't forget it is legal for it to make demons fly out of your nose too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third case, the compiler is alerting you of an out of bound access. The standard doesn't require it to complain but it does so.

For the first two cases there is no point in thinking what is happening. You said the first program runs *fine*. It doesn't - It has an UB.

For your question about how 3 & 4 changes anything, it could be dependent on how the stack frame is layed out. Due to alignment difference maybe the return address gets mucked in one case but doesn't in another. You will have to look at the generated assembly file to see what is actually going wrong.

This https://godbolt.org/g/gqz39q shows that in case where you set the array size to be 3 it is placing `position` at `%rbp - 32` and `step` at `%rbp - 4`. So in case when you write `position[3]`, `step` is being overwritten ( I don't want to think about what is being written).

When you make size of `position` to be 4, it places `step` at `%rbp - 4` and `position` at `%rbp - 48`. Now you write to `position[4]` ie `%rbp - 48 + 4 * 8 = %rbp - 16`. This will write till `%rbp - 8`. So `%rbp - 4` (`step`) is not changed.

Long story short, the padding saved you in case 1 but not in case 2.

PS: Again this is specific to the chosen compiler gcc 6.2 with O0 optimization level. The reason could be entirely different in your case.

Comment: yes. it is quite strange that `4` does not show any sign but `3` does show me some warning. Also, `for` loop clearly does something more and is "safer" in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing mentioned in the C language that *stops you* from writing a code that access out of bound memory, standard just clearly mentions that any attempt of doing so will causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Any diagnostic, if provided is at sole discretion of the compiler, maybe tied to the supplied compiler options, standard mentions no requirement of this.

For example, [for some compiler, the last snippet compiles just fine](https://ideone.com/EBdNBL) (and receives runtime error, too).

***Note 1:** In the shown snippets, the statements are **not** initialization, they are **assignments**.*

***Note 2:** I've modified the code a bit, but the invalid accesses made are same*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //int step;             // remove unused variable warning
    double position[4];
    position[0] = 1;
    position[1] = 99;
    position[2] = 99;
    position[3] = 99;
    position[4] = 99;

    (void) position;          // suppress unused variable warning

    return 0;
}
```